# 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionBagInterface' not found

Tags: php, symfony, drupal

I am an end user of Drupal and I am trying to migrate my site (www.vagile.nl) from 8.1.x to 8.2.5. Now I am getting an HTTP 500 error, the phperror.txt says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionBagInterface' not found in D:\www\vagile.nl\www\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag.php on line 24

When I look at the directory structure there is no directory in Symfony called Component. In the PHP file it says:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!!
Cheers Tom.

Answer (score 0):

It may not have been installed properly during the update. I am not a Drupal expert, but Symfony components are normally managed with Composer; if there is a `composer.json` or `composer.lock` file in your project, you may need to [install dependencies with composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-with-drupal).

Have you tried a `composer install`? If you haven't got composer already, you can download it from https://getcomposer.org/